# PiCamera and OpenCV imdecode always returning None

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I have a problem using OpenCV on Raspberry PI with the PiCamera. This is my code:

```
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = ( 320, 240 )
camera.framerate = 60
rawCapture = PiRGBArray( camera, size=( 320, 240 ) )
time.sleep(1)
start = time.time()
    
for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):


    # and occupied/unoccupied text
    images = frame.array

    # show the frame
    cv2.imshow("Frame", images)
    

    cv_img = images.astype(np.uint8)
    
    gray  = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(cv_img, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    image = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(cv_img, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
    
    print("IMAGE: ",image)
    print("GRAY: ",gray)
```

image and gray are always None while images and cv_image contains the right frame. I can't really understand why it won't work, Could you please help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please try adding suitable code to check the return status of all the functions you call - why does nobody bother checking anything worked any more?

Comment: I checked already all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found `picamera.array` to be a reliable way to bridge between `picamara` and `cv2`. The [docs](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_array.html) have some examples that aren't far off from yours.

Once you're squarely in `cv2` territory,

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

is the typical way to do the grayscale conversion. Doing it by way of `imdecode` is excessive.